# Example of contravariance

Tags: scala, contravariance

I am thinking of the following example to illustrate why contravariance is useful.

Let's consider a GUI framework with `Widgets`, `Events`, and `Event Listeners`.

```
abstract class Event;
class KeyEvent extends Event
class MouseEvent extends Event

trait EventListener[-E] { def listen(e:E) }
```

Let `Widgets` define the following methods:

```
def addKeyEventListener(listener:EventListener[KeyEvent])
def addMouseEventListener(listener:EventListener[MouseEvent])
```

These methods accept only "specific" event listeners, which is fine. However I would like to define also "kitchen-sink" listeners, which listen to all events, and pass such listeners to the "add listener" methods above.

For instance, I would like to define `LogEventListener` to log all incoming events

```
class LogEventListener extends EventListener[Event] {
   def listen(e:Event) { log(event) }
}
```

Since the trait `EventListener` is *contravariant* in `Event` we can pass `LogEventListener` to all those "add listener" methods without losing their type safety.

Does it make sense ?

Comment: +1 good question, bad accept-rate. sad!

Comment: How is this a question? If you were checking if the given code had any flaws, perhaps you wanted to post in codereview.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 7):

It makes sense to me, anyway. And it is also one of the most intuitive examples I have seen: something which listens to all events naturally will listen to key events or mouse events.

Answer (score 7):

Makes sense to me too. As a rule of thumb, a parametrized type `Type[A]` should be contravariant with respect to its type parameter `A` **each time it is meant to accept instances of `A` to do something with them by means of accepting them as parameters**.

For instance, the Java type `Comparator[T]`, if it had been defined in Scala, would have been contravariant: a `Comparator[Any]` should be a subtype of `Comparator[String]`, as it can compare all objects a `Comparator[String]` can compare, and more. The most general example is the argument types of the `FunctionX` classes, which are all contravariant.